# Example of an object which is not a subspace

Tags: vector-spaces

Consider the real vector space of all functions from $\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$.
Suppose we have the subset defined by:
$$f(0)=1+f(1)$$

Now I want to prove that this is not a subspace.
My first observation would be that $$(f+ g)(0)=1+(f+ g)(1)$$, However, when we add that two functions separately we get:
$$f(0) +g(0)=1+f(1) +1 +g(1) =2 + (f + g) (1)$$
Is this reasoning valid? It simply means that we cannot add elements and stay in the same set.

I also notice that the defined addition is commutative, associative, but there also would be no identity function satisfying this property, as the zero function is also not in there take $f(x)=0$ then $ f(0)=0 \not = 1+0$. Are there other properties that fail, which I am missing?

Comment: This is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You proved more than you needed to prove. Yes, if you sum any two elements of the set, the sum doesn't belong to it. A concrete example will do then. For instance, take $f(x)=g(x)=-x+1$. Then $f$ and $g$ belong to the set, but not their sum.

Or you can just note that the null function (which is the $0$ of the whole space) does not belong to the set.

Comment: Maybe you mean $f(x)=-x+1.$

Comment: I like the addition of a concrete example :)

Comment: For $f(x)=-x+1$, notice that  $f(0)=1$ and thus $1+f(1)=1 -1 +1=1$, therefore $f(0)=1+f(1)$. But adding two such functions is a great way to see it all crumble down :D

Comment: @mfl Again, thanks. I don't what went through my mind. Actually, $f(x)=-x$ would be enough.